# Reading image path with "ImageIO.read" to be displayed in a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, embedded-resource, javax.imageio

Full local path (`C:\\Users\\workspace\\myproject\\src\\eclipse\\mainclass\\icons\\my-image.png`) works fine, but using the short path like in the code below, gives an exception `javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!`.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    JLabel lab_h1 = new JLabel();
    BufferedImage img = null;

    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("icons/my-image.png"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Image dimg = img.getScaledInstance(140, 40,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

    lab_h1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(dimg));
```

Comment: You don't want to use new File you want to use a resource. What is the name of your class? You should do `new ImageIcon(MyClassName.class.getResource());` Then you don't need to use a BufferedImage at all.

Comment: Which version of java are you using? Which Eclipse version? What is the name of the class containing the code you posted in your question? Is that class in a package? If it is, what is the package name? [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) contains a lot of good advice on what constitutes a good question in _stackoverflow_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having, when you try to open a file with a relative path it looks relative to where you run the program. Instead of hoping to get the path correct, you can use a Resource.

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read( 
       YourClassName.class.getResource(
             "/mainclass/icons/my-image.png"
       ) 
 );
```

I think you might need to tinker with the path since I don't know what is your package structure. I am also assuming that eclipse will bundle resource files that are in your source folder.

Comment: Your code solved the problem. I think I was taking a wrong approach using "new File" instead of resource. It is reading the image path now correctly.

Comment: @MELS glad to hear it worked. Files are good when you want to read files that are not included with your app. Since you keep this in the source, I expected you want to include this with your app.